VPC SQS Endpoint dont show any dataflow for event from S3 to SQS and SQS to Lambda
I've a S3 bucket that notifies SQS for put and copy events.
and SQS is trigger private Lambda.
Lambda is running under a VPC in private subnet.
Data is flowing successfully and S3 to SQS and to private Lambda.
Now I've create SQS VPC endpoint and in monitoring tab I dont see any graph.

I want to see graph in SQS VPC endpoint

Is there any particular reason why you have attached the AWS Lambda function to the VPC? Will it be accessing any resources inside the VPC, such as an Amazon RDS database?

The flow is:

Amazon S3 sends a message to the Amazon SQS queue
The AWS Lambda service polls the Amazon SQS queue for messages

Both of these operations run in the AWS backplane and do not traverse your VPC. It is correct that you will not see this traffic in the VPC Endpoint.
The VPC Endpoints for SQS will, however, be used by any resources in your VPC that call the Amazon SQS service. For example, code running on an EC2 instance in that VPC will communicate with SQS via the VPC Endpoint for SQS.
